# How to design a android chat bubble with preview of any media file

Tags: java, android, xml

[image: I need to design an xml that has a chat bubble that's able to preview any media file like this]

How can a design a chat bubble that won't show preview of image only but also other types of media files like videos, pdf, word media files.

Comment: You can use 9 patch images for that

Comment: @Burhanuddin Is the link to guide me as am still a novice developer

Answer (score 1):

You can use 9-Patch Images for bubble background.
You can Draw 9-patch tool is a WYSIWYG editor included in Android Studio that allows you to create bitmap images that automatically resize to accommodate the contents of the view and the size of the screen. Selected parts of the image are scaled horizontally or vertically based on indicators drawn within the image.

Please follow this [LINK](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html)

You can also use Android Asset Generator to generate 9-patch image [HERE](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example)